# Angular: Adding a custom SVG Mat-icon, Error retrieving icon :add1! Cannot read property 'includes' of null

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material, mat-icon

I followed this tutorial for the most part, [Adding Custom SVG MatIcon](https://dev.to/elasticrash/using-custom-made-svg-icons-through-the-angular-material-library-2pif). The mat-icon component is displayed but the svg image is not and I am getting an error in the console.

`Error retrieving icon :hllogo! Cannot read property 'includes' of null`.

This error message tells me very little. Is it complaining the svg does not exist? Just in case, while registering the svg as an icon, I have tried multiple variations of the relative paths to the svg file, but all of them seem to throw this error. Any idea what the error actually means?

PS: I generated the SVG file from a PNG file using an online engine, [SVG Convertor](https://convertio.co/png-svg/), if that makes a difference.

The reference to the icon in the html

```
<button
      *ngIf="true"
      class="action-buttons"
      mat-icon-button
      matTooltip="Team synced"
      matTooltipShowDelay="500"
    >
      <mat-icon svgIcon="hllogo"></mat-icon>
    </button>
```

The Typescript:

```
//icon.service.ts
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { MatIconRegistry } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })

  export class IconService {
  
    constructor(
      private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
      private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }
  
    public registerIcons(): void {
      this.matIconRegistry
            .addSvgIcon('hllogo', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../assets/img/HLThumb.svg'));
    }  
  }
```

The reference to the icon service in the `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IconService } from './shared/services/icon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private iconService: IconService
  ) {
    this.iconService.registerIcons();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using another SVG not generated from PNG to make sure that isn't your issue? Nothing in your code looks incorrect. Also I would try using <mat-icon> outside of the button as a test as well to see if something from the button is breaking it. Lastly, if none of those work, I'd try to register the custom SVG right in the component. You can follow this guide as well: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-svg-icons-angular-material

Comment: Thanks @BrianSmith! Great suggestions but neither of them resolved the issue. I am debugging the framework code where the error is being thrown. I will add it here if I find something.

Comment: Any news on this? Experiencing the same, strange behavior

Comment: @tris, I ended up using the png itself instead of an svg. Something like  `<button> .....
      <mat-icon> <img src="../assets/imgs/hlimage"/></mat-icon>
    </button>`